# Trying to change selected text format in MS Access rich text field

Tags: vba, ms-access-2007

I've been trying to find a solution for an MS Access 2007 application I'm building for work. One of the forms allows for creation of a particular kind of document, with the main body of the text being a rich text field. What I'd like to do is have the ability to select a section of text and then press a formatting button and cause the selected text to change - not unlike the submission box here, in fact. I'm pretty solid in Access and VBA, and have tried using SelText and so on, but I just can't seem to get it to work.

Can anyone shed any light on how I could go about this? I know I could just use keyboard shortcuts, but the database is aimed at people whose computer skills are relatively minimal.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help!

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right way ;)

If I were you, i would create buttons like on this site (with B for bold and I for italic), the user can select text and click on the buttons.

Now, for making the selected text bold, use

```
RichTextBox.SelBold = True
'or just toggle the value
RichTextBox.SelBold = Not RichTextBox.SelBold
```

for italic:

```
RichTextBox.SelItalic = True
```

for colors:

```
RichTextBox.SelColor = vbRed
```

and so on...

Comment: Agh, I feel like an idiot! Thank you so much, Manu, that really helps a lot.